# Sub-theme not inheriting CSS

Tags: 8, theming

I have checked all the similar questions on here, and the Drupal forums, but to no avail. I followed the Drupal documentation for creating a sub-theme, verbatim, but my new theme is not inheriting styles, at all.

Any idea what might be causing this issue, aside from what's already been suggested?

Below is our info.yml file:

```
name: MF Conference
type: theme
description: This is a mf sub theme of Conference Lite
core: '8.x'
# Defines the base theme
base theme: conference_lite
# Defines libraries group in which we can add css/js.
libraries:
  - mf_conference/global-styling
# Regions
regions:
  slideout: 'Slideout'
  header_top_highlighted_first: 'Header Top Highlighted First'
  header_top_highlighted_second: 'Header Top Highlighted Second'
  header_top_first: 'Header Top First'
  header_top_second: 'Header Top Second'
  header_first: 'Header First'
  header: 'Header Second'
  header_third: 'Header Third'
  banner: 'Banner'
  system_messages: 'System Messages'
  content_top: 'Content Top'
  content_top_highlighted: 'Content Top Highlighted'
  content: 'Content'
  sidebar_first: 'Sidebar First'
  sidebar_second: 'Sidebar Second'
  content_bottom_first: 'Content Bottom First'
  content_bottom_second: 'Content Bottom Second'
  featured_top: 'Featured Top'
  featured: 'Featured'
  featured_bottom: 'Featured Bottom'
  sub_featured: 'Sub Featured'
  highlighted_top: 'Highlighted Top'
  highlighted: 'Highlighted'
  footer_top_first: 'Footer Top First'
  footer_top_second: 'Footer Top Second'
  footer_first: 'Footer First'
  footer_second: 'Footer Second'
  footer_third: 'Footer Third'
  footer_fourth: 'Footer Fourth'
  footer_fifth: 'Footer Fifth'
  footer_bottom: 'Footer Bottom'
  sub_footer_first: 'Subfooter First'
  footer: 'Subfooter Second'
  hidden_blocks_collection: 'Hidden blocks collection'
```

I've also tested with another base-theme and created a new sub-theme, again following the directions listed here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-a-drupal-8-sub-theme-or-sub-theme-of-sub-theme

I know the CSS isn't inheriting because when I check the Inspector it doesn't have any information from the parent themes CSS files--only global.css

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! :-) And when you create a subtheme of Bartik, is it the same? Or when you install just Bartik, do styles get loaded?

Comment: Hi @leymannx, so, no, unfortunately when I create a sub-theme of Bartik I get the same issue. Installing Bartik on it's own works fine--the styles load and functionality is working as expected, but the sub-theme in the core/themes folder doesn't work either.

Comment: I have an update, which hopefully could lead to a solution. I'm upgrading from a Drupal 7 site, to Drupal 8. The themes and subthemes work perfectly until after the update. Once I complete the Upgrade module, the sub-themes break. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: This needs to be added to your question. Not as comment. Simply edit your question and provide the steps to reproduce your issue there.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with not inheriting, is it that the CSS files do not show up in the HTML output, or is it the order of the css files that prevents the styles from being used? Besides that your question does not include the mf_conference.libraries.yml file. There could be some issues as wel.